# uncheck (removing) last item in checkbox and check(adding) other at the same time , keeps the unchecked value and adds other checked value

Tags: arrays, reactjs, arraylist, react-hooks, use-state

here only one person is assigned
[image: here only one person is assigned]

Now, unchecked the previous person(already added), and check other other
[image]

onSubmit , it adds then both

[image]

here is my code :

```
 const [assignCustomerId, setAssignCustomerId] = useState([]);

  const handleOnChange = (id, event) => {
    //checking the already present customers by id
    const alreadyAssignedDeliveryMan = deliveryBoy?.assigned_customers.map(
      (d) => d.milkman_buyer_customer_id
    );

    // here, if already customer is assigned in database then pushing new checked
    // and keeping the database data also
    if (assignCustomerId.length === 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < alreadyAssignedDeliveryMan.length; i++) {
        assignCustomerId.push(alreadyAssignedDeliveryMan[i]);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("null");
    }
    //if user checked, then push it into state array
    //if user unchecked , then removing the item from array
    const checked = event.target.checked;
    if (checked === true) {
      assignCustomerId.push(id);
      setAssignCustomerId(assignCustomerId);
    } else if (checked === false) {
      for (var i = assignCustomerId.length - 1; i >= -1; i--) {
        if (assignCustomerId[i] === id) {
          assignCustomerId.splice(i, 1);
          setAssignCustomerId(assignCustomerId);
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are mutating your `assignCustomerId` state and saving the same array reference back into state. When updating the "already assigned delivery persons" the code pushes directly into the `assignCustomerId` array. Also, when `checked` is true the code is pushing directly into the `assignCustomerId` array, and when `checked` is false the `.splice` does an in-place mutation

```
if (assignCustomerId.length === 0) {
  for (let i = 0; i < alreadyAssignedDeliveryMan.length; i++) {
    assignCustomerId.push(alreadyAssignedDeliveryMan[i]); // <-- state mutation!
  }
} else {
  console.log("null");
}

const checked = event.target.checked;
if (checked === true) {
  assignCustomerId.push(id); // <-- state mutation!
  setAssignCustomerId(assignCustomerId);
} else if (checked === false) {
  for (var i = assignCustomerId.length - 1; i >= -1; i--) {
    if (assignCustomerId[i] === id) {
      assignCustomerId.splice(i, 1); // <-- state mutation!
      setAssignCustomerId(assignCustomerId);
    }
  }
}
```

## Solution

When adding a value to the `assignCustomerId` array create a shallow copy and append the new element value(s). When removing a value from the `assignCustomerId array then filter it and return a new array reference.

```
if (!assignCustomerId.length) {
  setAssignCustomerId(state => state.concat(alreadyAssignedDeliveryMan));
} else {
  console.log("null");
}

const { checked } = event.target;

if (checked) {
  setAssignCustomerId(state => [...state, id]);
} else {
  setAssignCustomerId(state => state.filter((el) => el !== id));
}
```

Comment: yes its working , but then my old state changes are reflecting when i change other users data as i have used select tab for users and setting state to that user every time , the previous state plus my new state is getting added

Comment: @priyapathak What part of your code snippet is reacting to changing the user data? If this is the case then when that happens you likely want to reset this `assignCustomerId` back to an empty array. Is this an issue external to the state updates in `handleOnChange`?

Comment: setAssignCustomerId(assignCustomerId);      :   ....i am using react-query and setting my state like this on mutation

Comment: @priyapathak `setAssignCustomerId(assignCustomerId);` will only enqueue a state update to the current value. I'm saying somewhere you want to reset back to an empty array it seems, something like `setAssignCustomerId([]);` where ever you are updating user data.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you in remove part

```js
let index = assignCustomerId.findIndex(x=>x===id)
assignCustomerId.splice(index, 1);
setAssignCustomerId([...assignCustomerId]);
```